# Firmware update through OTA - identical binary files received from different server, one is working and another is not

Tags: binaryfiles, firmware, ota

For Firmware update, I tested with Barracks service where i uploaded my updated file and worked fine after downloading in hardware device, but when I tested this with our server, it didn't worked. I uploaded the same file and I received the exact file similar to what i was receiving from Barracks.
Other details -
Checksum of these two files are same
Content length is different for the response
utf8 format is used in both the cases.

Please help.

Comment: Could be network setting issue?

Comment: How can checksum be same and length different? Use better checksum algorithm?

Comment: @Arkadiy Content length in response headers are different, not the content length of file. File is of 56244 bytes from both the server, but the content length of response header is 54044 from Barracks and 73054 from my own server. Still mine is not working and Barracks is working.